# Listview doesn't show the item correctly after doing filter operation

Tags: android

I'm trying to filter the custom listview Adapter but doesn't work well.

I'm getting all values(After filtering , in publishResults() method) but its not affecting my listview.
Where is the mistake in my Adapter Class.

This is my Adapter class Mlt_sixTextviewAdapter.java where ModelFilter is 
the class to perform Filter Operation.
After doing Filter Operation I'm getting FILTERED VALUES IN publishResults

```
      public class Mlt_sixTextviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MLT_Details> implements
                    Filterable {

                List<MLT_Details> alllst;
                List<MLT_Details> list;
                List<MLT_Details> filterlst;
                Context context;
                TextView txtitem;
                TextView txtdesc;
                TextView txtfrom;
                TextView txtto;
                TextView txtrecqty;
                TextView txtuom;

                private ModelFilter filter;

                @Override
                public Filter getFilter() {
                    if (filter == null) {
                        filter = new ModelFilter();
                    }
                    return filter;
                }

                public Mlt_sixTextviewAdapter(Context context, List<MLT_Details> value) {
                    super(context, R.layout.eight_textview, value);
                    this.context = context;
                    this.list = value;
                    this.alllst = new ArrayList<MLT_Details>(list);
                    this.filterlst = new ArrayList<MLT_Details>(alllst);
                    getFilter();

                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    final int pos = position;

                    if (convertView == null) {

                        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.eight_textview, null);

                        txtitem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullItemNo);
                        txtdesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullDesc);
                        txtfrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullLoc);
                        txtto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullord);
                        txtrecqty = (TextView) convertView
                                .findViewById(R.id.txt_fullrecqty);
                        txtuom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fullUom);

                        convertView.setTag(new OrdersViewHolder(txtitem, txtdesc, txtfrom,
                                txtto, txtrecqty, txtuom));

                    } else {
                        OrdersViewHolder viewHolder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView
                                .getTag();
                    }

                    OrdersViewHolder holder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                    holder.txtitem.setText(alllst.get(pos).getMlt_itemno());
                    holder.txtdesc.setText(alllst.get(pos).getMlt_description());
                    holder.txtfrom.setText(alllst.get(pos).getMlt_from());
                    holder.txtto.setText((alllst.get(pos).getMlt_to()));
                    holder.txtrecqty.setText((alllst.get(pos).getMlt_qty()));
                    holder.txtuom.setText(alllst.get(pos).getMlt_uom());

                    return convertView;

                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return filterlst.size();
                }

                @Override
                public MLT_Details getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return filterlst.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }

                /** Holds child views for one row. */
                static class OrdersViewHolder {

                    TextView txtitem;
                    TextView txtdesc;
                    TextView txtfrom;
                    TextView txtto;
                    TextView txtrecqty;
                    TextView txtuom;

                    /*
                     * TextView txtshipvia; TextView txtcomment;
                     */

                    public OrdersViewHolder(TextView txtitem, TextView txtdesc,
                            TextView txtpick, TextView txtordqty, TextView txtrecqty,
                            TextView txtuom) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                        this.txtitem = txtitem;
                        this.txtdesc = txtdesc;
                        this.txtfrom = txtpick;
                        this.txtto = txtordqty;
                        this.txtrecqty = txtrecqty;
                        this.txtuom = txtuom;

                    }

                    public TextView getTxtitem() {
                        return txtitem;
                    }

                    public TextView getTxtdesc() {
                        return txtdesc;
                    }

                    public TextView getTxtfrom() {
                        return txtfrom;
                    }

                    public TextView getTxtto() {
                        return txtto;
                    }

                    public TextView getTxtrecqty() {
                        return txtrecqty;
                    }

                    public TextView getTxtuom() {
                        return txtuom;
                    }

                    public void setTxtitem(TextView txtitem) {
                        this.txtitem = txtitem;
                    }

                    public void setTxtdesc(TextView txtdesc) {
                        this.txtdesc = txtdesc;
                    }

                    public void setTxtfrom(TextView txtfrom) {
                        this.txtfrom = txtfrom;
                    }

                    public void setTxtto(TextView txtto) {
                        this.txtto = txtto;
                    }

                    public void setTxtrecqty(TextView txtrecqty) {
                        this.txtrecqty = txtrecqty;
                    }

                    public void setTxtuom(TextView txtuom) {
                        this.txtuom = txtuom;
                    }

                }

                private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                            ArrayList<MLT_Details> filteredItems = new ArrayList<MLT_Details>();

                            for (int i = 0, l = alllst.size(); i < l; i++) {
                                MLT_Details customer = alllst.get(i);
                                String strNum = customer.getMlt_itemno();// tHhCustomer_number();
                                String strDesc = customer.getMlt_description();
                                if (strNum.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                                    /* || strDesc.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) */
                                    filteredItems.add(customer);
                            }
                            result.count = filteredItems.size();
                            result.values = filteredItems;
                        } else {
                            synchronized (this) {
                                result.values = alllst;// ModelItemsArray;
                                result.count = alllst.size();
                            }

                        }
                        return result;
                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                            FilterResults results) {
                        filterlst = (ArrayList<MLT_Details>) results.values;
                        if (results.count == 0)
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        else
                            for (int i = 0, l = filterlst.size(); i < l; i++) {
                                add(filterlst.get(i));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                System.out.println("Fileter Item coming"
                                        + filterlst.get(i).getMlt_itemno());
                            }

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you try calling `clear()` before adding filtered results with `add(...)` Also you probably want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` out side of your for loop, but that's not the cause of your issue,

Comment: I tried by giving clear() before adding filtered result...but doesnt help me @ci_

Comment: Always its coming first rows....Any Idea @ci_

Comment: Pay more attention to formatting and leave out the chit-chat a per the help-tour